# onClick in anchor tage with span inside it, not getting triggered in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, anchor

I'm trying to call function `onClick` in anchor tag which has span in it but it's not working in IE.

In the code below, the `onClick` on remove function `iViewCommand()` is not getting triggered:

```
<a class="rmLink" 
    onclick="javascript:window.dashboard.iViewCommand(236, 
    'delete');return false;" href="javascript:void(0);" style="width: 129px;">
    <span class="rmText">Remove</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the onClick to the span element?

Comment: @Davide Vitali : Same output. The issue is inconsistent after multiple clicks once in a while it fires the method.

Comment: Why not putting the `rmText` class directly on the anchor tag?